# Two independednt axis in Dynamic Data Display DevMarkerChart

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I am new user of d3, I am trying to plot two different graph on independent y axis. Like Line graph on left side y axis similarly bar chart on right side y- axis.

As per the sample I have used InjectedPlotter for bar series, however I not able to plot independent y axis for two different chart type. I can do this easily for two line chart. By default both the chart are potting from left side y axis.[image]

Early help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it using dependent plotter. I got a solution after using the latest version of [Data Dynamic Display](http://d3future.codeplex.com/)